# Why is my thread not being notified?

Tags: java, multithreading, scjp

In exercise

> Make a program where you have a fashion and a sewing machine, so the Operator enter data
>   width and height, notify the sewing machine in order to perform their job.

The `Operator` receive data and process and notify machine.  `Machine` receive data and finalizes the process.

However, when I run, the `Maquina` thread is not being notified and the machine and the `Operator` is in infinite loop receiving data.

```
public class Operator extends Thread {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int altura, largura;
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            synchronized (this) {
                System.out.print("Altura: ");
                altura = in.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Largura: ");
                largura = in.nextInt();
                notify();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getForma() {
        return "Forro de mesa : " + (altura * largura);
    }
}

public class Maquina extends Thread{

    private Operator c;

    public Maquina(Operator c) {
        this.c = c;
    }


    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            synchronized (c) {
                try {

                    System.out.println("Waiting shape...");
                    c.wait();

                    System.out.println("init drawn...");
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);

                    System.out.println("drawing...");
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);

                    System.out.println(c.getForma() + ", finalized");

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?  Are you asking why it is looping?

Comment: is always in the loop and not notified thread machine.
From my understanding, should receive the data from the User and pass to the machine whenever I receive data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In running your code the problem seems to be that the `"Waiting shape..."` message is never reached.  This surprises me but it seems like the `while (true) { synchronized(c)` is never letting the `Maquina` into the `synchronized` block.

Adding a small sleep at the front of the `Operator.run()` method fixes the problem.  It gives time for the `Maquina` to get the lock and enter `wait()`.

```
while (true) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        return;
    }
    synchronized (this) {
        System.out.print("Altura: ");
        altura = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Largura: ");
        largura = in.nextInt();
        notify();
    }
}
```

Comment: Gray, but the `Operator` never releases the lock... is this the cause? `wait()` release immediately the locked object but the `notify()` not? can be that?

Comment: The `Operator` released the lock when it leaves the `synchronized {}` block.  The loop is _outside_ of this block.

Comment: Gray, I didn't understand why this happen, the wait() thread should get the lock after it leaves the synchronized block, is not it? why we need put the spleep? the time is not enough to the trhead get the lock?

Comment: I'm not sure @PauloDiogo.  Maybe the optimizer was moving the loop inside of the `synchronized` block.  Not sure.